# Scripting techniques : binding / embedding files using codes?

Tags: batch-file, binding, vbscript, scripting, embedding

ok so we all know that there is some awesome tools that allow you to bind a bunch of files no matter what extensions they have into one executable file ex: **EasyBinder** v 2.0 , or some other allow us to embed files into another one and extract them to specific locations when the file is run (extracting them without running them) like the one in **Advanced bat to exe converter** 
, but when trying to make a script i struggle to find a way to bind or embed random files according to user input , i know it's some advanced scripting or programming techniques and maybe impossible, but the fact that there is a lot of downloadable file binders that are so basic and seem to be created using a simple gui language makes me curious .

> *when googling "File binders" , i found a lot of programs not even close to 1mb size, and created by some starter programmers*

is there any way or any code in any scripting language that can bind files ?
waiting reply impatiently .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This - http://consolesoft.com/p/bhx/index.html will allow you to save a binary file as a a string inside batch file with the option to extract it.
Another way is to use certutil -> http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1562
you can embed a base64 string inside batch file with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` headers around the base64 string.

Comment: this is very helpful , i just still wonder if it's possible to have a function or command to bind files with other extensions ? or this is the further you can go without changing to a more functioning programming language

Comment: @SixPackScript - with this tools you can create ->http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:fA5mzPi0sccJ:www.hackforums.net/archive/index.php/thread-4500481.html+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=bg&lr=lang_en%7Clang_bg