# I need to use an image in .exe file

Tags: batch-file, exe

I have made a .bat file that opens an image file. I converted it to .exe file using bat2exe converter. Now what I need is,  that somehow I could add that image to the .exe file so that I do not have to keep it in same folder and instead just execute the exe. I am expecting it to be like a installer file that extracts the image to temp if necessary so that I can display it. Any ways I can work this around? Thanks in Advance.

> **I am not restricted to binding rather what I am hoping for, is that, if I could store image in BLOB form in the batch file itself so that
>   on conversion to exe I do not need to extract it to temp file or into
>   same folder rather let it be stored inside the program itself.
>   
>
> *If possible**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scripting techniques : binding / embedding files using codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518537/scripting-techniques-binding-embedding-files-using-codes)

Comment: This is not a batch file coding issue and is not on topic here. There are hundreds of programs available for creating self-extracting executables. I suggest you choose the one which best suits you, read up on it's usage and write some code if necessary. You may return here with that code as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46924097/edit) to your question should you require specific help with it at that time.

Comment: I am not restricted to binding rather what I was hoping for is that if I could store image in BLOB form in the batch file itself so that on conversion to exe I do not need to extract it to temp file or into same folder rather let it be stored inside the program itself. 
*If possible

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free programming service. Here you choose your own method, research it and create your own code, posting it here should issues arise at run time.